# Passing List<Class> as argument, C#, using "ref" keyword

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

friends!

So I have been writing a simple program. Basically, I have a class (3 strings, 1 int, some methods). I am initializing the values of objects of this class from a text file. I am using List for this.
The problem is that initialization is a separate function. I had List BOTH declared AND initialized in this function. However, I might need it in other functions, including "Program.Main".

Should I make a "Global" class and put make a **public List< Class >** ? I decided to just declare it in my Program.Main function as of now. However, I am not sure, if a List is passed by value or by reference.  I found a page on the Web, which suggests using **ref** keyword. Now I have:

```
public Class FooClass
{...}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      List<FooClass> fooDB = new List<FooClass>;
      initFromFile(ref fooDB);
    }

    private static initFromFile(ref List<FooClass> fooDB)
    {
       using (StreamReader ... )
       {
          while( ... )
          {
             ...
             fooDB.Add(new FooClass(args))
          }
       }
     }//initFromFile

}//Program
```

Should I keep on working like this? Or are there any crucial suggestions? Maybe "ref" isn't a good practice at all?

**TLDR: Should i make a global *List* or pass it as a reference or another way(suggest). If passing by reference, then should I use a *ref* keyword or is there another way?**

Thanks in advance,

~~~hlfrmn

Comment: Whatever page you found that on is completely wrong and should be ignored.

Comment: Why are you even using `ref` there is no reason to from the code you shown. You would only need to use a `ref` if you had `fooDB = Somthing;` in your `initFromFile` function.

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: D Stanley's answer is correct and I would just add that to answer the other part of your question, no, you shouldn't make a global List.
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: @SLaks It's just stupid me. Fast-googled "c# pass argument by reference", saw "ref" and just typed it in immediately. The article only had examples with INT.

Comment: @akousmata Yeah, I really didn't want to make a global, which is mostly why I asked if the "in-Main declaration" was fine. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way your program is structured is just fine, except there's no need toi use `ref`.  `List<T>` is a *reference type*, meaning that the *value* that is passed to the function is actually a reference ("pointer" in C/C++ terms) to a `List<T>` instance.  So any modifications to the list within the method will be available when the function returns.

The only reason you would use `ref` is if you wanted to point `fooDB` to a new *instance*:

```
private static initFromFile(ref List<FooClass> fooDB)
{

  fooDB = new List<FooClass>; // if the parameter was not passed by reference 
                               // this instance would not be used by the caller.
  using (StreamReader ... ){
  while( ... )
  {
    ...
    fooDB.Add(new FooClass(args))
  }}
}//initFromFile
```

**EDIT**

Reading the first part of your question more closely, it seems like `fooDB` should possibly be a *class member* that is initialized:

```
class Program
{
    private static List<FooClass> fooDB;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      initFromFile();
      foreach(FooClass f in fooDB)
      {
          // do something
      }
    }

    private static initFromFile()
    {
       fooDB = new List<FooClass>();
       using (StreamReader ... )
       {
          while( ... )
          {
             ...
             fooDB.Add(new FooClass(args))
          }
       }
     }//initFromFile

}//Program
```

Comment: And even in that example, you wouldn't use `ref`, you'd use `out`. :)

Comment: @hvd true - if you're not using the reference that's passed in then `out` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. After i gave it a second thought, i guessed it would probably get passed-by-reference anyway. Good to know that structure is fine, though. I'd love to put this list into the FooClass itself, but I see no way to do so, and then came to choice of either declaring a global or declaring in Main. Not an easy decision for me, since I prefer having as few arguments as possible.

Comment: @hlfrmn See my updated answer.  In this case it looks like adding a private property to `Program` is more appropriate.  Then it can be used by any method within `Program`.

Comment: @DStanley Oh boy! Now this is what I was dreaming about. Thanks for the update, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to set the value of `fooDB` directly inside the `initFromFile` function, you don't need to pass it as a `ref` parameter. Note that classes in .NET are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx), so when you pass the list to method, the method parameter refers to the same instance that was passed in (as opposed to [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)). [`ref` parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) are used to modify what value that the both the parameter and the variable that was passed into the method reference. Using `ref` parameters is almost never necessary in typical .NET development.

Just pass it normally, and it will work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<FooClass> fooDB = new List<FooClass>;
    initFromFile(fooDB);
}
private static initFromFile(List<FooClass> fooDB)
{
    using (StreamReader ... ) 
    {
        while( ... )
        {
            ...
            fooDB.Add(new FooClass(args))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic lists are `reference types` hence you don't need to use `ref` keyword.If you make a change in your list on your method, it will affect your actual list.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code sample above, I would suggest that your initFromFile() method just return the list, i.e.

```
public Class FooClass
{...}
class Program
{static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var fooData = initFromFile();
}

private static List<FooClass> initFromFile()
{
  var fooDB = new List<FooClass>();

  using (StreamReader ... ){
  while( ... )
  {
    ...
    fooDB.Add(new FooClass(args))
  }}

  return fooDB;
}//initFromFile
}//Program
```

Comment: Of course, my stupid program is only dealing with miserable amounts of data. However, is it not a bad thing- to be copying a list around? Also, should I add a "destroy" in the end of your version of initFromFile? Or is it handled by the compiler in some way?

Comment: @hlfrmn: You're not copying a list around. You're copying a *reference* to a list around, because `List<T>` is a reference type. The value of your `fooDB` variable isn't a list - it's a reference.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Thank you, 4 years was more enough to let this sink in :)

Comment: @hlfrmn: I do apologize - I was looking at another question that referred to this one, and got a bit confused. Sorry!